# PHP/Java Bridge, How to pass parameter to constructor method when create the instance?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

```
package test;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT = "8080";
    static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner = php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner
            .getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        runner.waitFor();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php require_once("/path/to/Java.inc");
$hello_world = new java("test.HelloWorld");
?>
```

I know the code above can create a HelloWorld instance.

But what if the constructor of HelloWorld.java has some parameters?How to write the php code?

Comment: $hello_world = new java("test.HelloWorld",$parameter0,$parameter1);

Answer (score 0):

here is my code,hope this can help you a bit.

php file:

```
**<?php require_once("C:/jetty-distribution-9.3.7.v20160115/webapps/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
$world = new java("HelloWorld");
echo $world->hello(array("from PHP"));
?>**
```

here $world is my object and you can pass the parameter of java in last line.